# Multidimensional array of strings and functions

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

in C...

Assuming I have a multidimensional array of strings like this:

```
//Array declared in main. Will Contains strings from user-input later on
char myArray[10][10];
```

Why cant I pass the array over to this function

```
//Function prototype:
void myFunc (char *mynewArray[]);

// Function call in main()
myFunc(myArray);
```

My understanding of arrays and pointers is when I call myFunc, I am passing the array's address over. The receiving function receives this address stores in as a pointer. I then should be able to access mynewArray[1] in myFunc. However it does not work?

Am I understanding arrays and pointers wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void myFunc (char *mynewArray[]);
```

is equivalent in C to:

```
void myFunc (char **mynewArray);
```

but the value of you array is `char (*)[10]`.

You need to have something like:

```
void myFunc (char (*mynewArray)[10]);
```

or its equivalent

```
void myFunc (char mynewArray[][10]);
```

Remember:

1. the value of an array is a pointer to its first element (the array object is *converted* to a pointer)
2. in a function declaration a parameter of type array of `T` is *ajusted* to a type pointer to `T`

Comment: Hmm thanks for the input. So its not possible for me to keep my function prototype as 

void myFunc (char *mynewArray[]);

and yet continue accepting multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @kype No, it uses an incorrect parameter type. You need to use the prototype I showed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint on how to read C declarations:

1. Find the identifier name
2. Look right
3. Look left

Has to be modified with parentheses for precidence, but it can be widely applied.

When you see [ say "an array"

When you see ( say "a function"

For example: `char *mynewArray[]`

(name) mynewArray is (look right) an array of (look left) pointers to char.

And next: `char myArray[10][10];`

myArray is an array of 10 arrays of 10 chars.

What the difference?

If you increment `mynewArray` the address will change by the sizeof one pointer to char.

If you increment `myArray` the address will change by the sizeof 10 chars.

That's why they are different.

In function prototypes the leftmost set of `[]` should be empty (or replaced by `*`), subsequent sets of `[]` should have a size.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a frequent question that `comp.lang.c` newsgroup had a FAQ entry just for that question for years: [So what is meant by the “equivalence of pointers and arrays” in C?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

TL;DR: *Pointer arithmetic* and *array indexing* are equivalent. So even though they are different (array allocate storage, pointer just reference a memory address), pointers can be used to access elements of an array or to simulate an array.

The standard says:

> A reference to an object of type array-of-T which appears in an expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T.

The exceptions are when the array is an operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operators.

---

What this means is that in your code, `myArray` is equivalent to `&myArray[0]`. The type of `& myArray[0]` is `char *[10]`. This is not the same type as `char **` or even `char *[]` as they have different memory layout. And thus the compiler is refusing the conversion (that is invalid).

The confusion comes from one dimension array. Even tough the types `char *`, `char []` and `char [10]` are different (they have different memory layout), if you define variables of the two array types, they would decay to be equivalent to `&a[0]` which is of type `char *`.